# chartjs how to change decimal to integers X-axis

Tags: chart.js

I have this chartjs code which is a horizontal bar chart

```
 new Chart(document.getElementById("bar-chart-grouped_E09"), {
                                    type: 'horizontalBar',
                                    data: {
                                      labels: E09_labels,
                                      datasets: [
                                        {
                                          label: "Male",
                                          backgroundColor: "#3e95cd",
                                          data: E09_M_values
                                        }, {
                                          label: "Female",
                                          backgroundColor: "#8e5ea2",
                                          data: E09_F_values
                                        }
                                      ]
                                    },
                                    options: {
                                      title: {
                                        display: true,
                                        text: 'Drug or chemical induced diabetes mellitus'
                                      }
                                    }
                                });
```

however the value for male is 0 then for female 1, then the graph's x-axis shows decimal values 0.2, 0.4....1, 1.2 and so on.

basically this is due to my max value being 1 but the data doesn't make sense if it shows decimal values. ideally the graph will be updated once there are more data added but as much as possible, I want to show real numbers to make the graph more realistic.

Answer (score 2):

Try to put this in your options, it will begin at zero(so that bars with value 1 could be displayed) and Math.trunc will remove decimals.

```
scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true,
                        userCallback: function (label, index, labels) {
                            if (Math.trunc(label) === label) {
                                return label;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }]
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the options of chartjs scales. You can set up your min, max, and step of your scale. With that you could make it so only 0 and 1 are displayed.